# Springboot Hateoas not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I updated my project's Springboot version from `1.5.10` to `2.2.2`. As per the documentation, I did all the necessary changes to resolve HATEOS related compilation errors. But now the HTTP response is not coming as expected. Now, I'm getting `"links"` instead of `"_links"`. Also,  I'm not getting `"_embedded"` attribute in response anymore.

I did below changes:

Replaced `ResourceSupport` with `RepresentationModel<T>`

Replaced `Resource` with `EntityModel`

Replaced `Resources` with `CollectionModel`

Please help me out in resolving this issue.

Comment: What `accept` headers is your client sending? Looks like you are receiving Collection+Json response rather than HAL. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.2.2/reference/html/#mediatypes HAL shoiuld be the default according to the specs (see 5.1) .

Comment: Upload a ready-to-run project in Github always helps others to check the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `hateoas` and `swagger` do not work together after `springboot 2.x.x`. I ended up replacing `swagger` with `springdoc-openapi-ui` for documentation.